# JavaServer Faces rate limiter

Tags: security, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2.2

Is there any standard way to limit the how often an user can call a JSF method?

NOTE: I want to rate limit a public page that does not require login, so I would prefer a solution that does not require the use of a session. A possible example would be the contact page.

Comment: If the page is public, how are you going to determine if current user has accesed the page before or not? Anyway, doing it based in JSF method calls shouldn't be the way, unless you want to count how many times a form is being sent for example.

Comment: @XtremeBiker: one example would be to count the number of time an action is executed from a certain IP.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9830996/1199132) you've got the code to obtain a certain IP access using JSF. Note that registering the IP doesn't ensure it's the same user access. Your application should definitelly register this in `@ApplicationScoped`. Anyway, your question is too broad about what you want to achieve. You should narrow your target and later come here with more concrete questions (and code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing the rate limiting with nginx.

I have nginx in front of my glassfish server, and with nginx it is very easy to limit the number of request/second coming from a certain source.

nginx configuration: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html